# datomic query converter from SQL

Tags: datomic

I want to represent following SQL query in datomic

SELECT A.a C.c
FROM A, B, C
WHERE A.id = B.id and B.index = C.index

What willl be datomic query representation for this?

Also, will the same datomic query work if WHERE conditions are reversed i.e. we have "B.index = C.index and A.id = B.id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a literal translation:

```
(d/q '[:find ?a-val ?c-val
       :where
       [?A :a.id ?id]
       [?B :b.id ?id]
       [?B :b.index ?index]
       [?C :c.index ?index]
       [?A :a ?a-val]
       [?C :c ?c-val]]
  db)
```

I've written that so you should be able to see how to translate from the question to the answer.

Hopefully it's clear that using `?index` in two places that is doing the same job as `=` in the SQL where clause.

The clauses can be reordered anyhow and remain logically equivalent. The difference will be in performance: put the most narrowing/specific clauses first for better performance.

Some caveats:

Whether you want to have distinct attributes for the `index` and `id` concepts (for example `a.index` and `b.index` or only `index`) is down to your requirements. Datomic has good [docs](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html) and tutorials.

There are many differences between SQL and Datalog, for example no tables in Datalog (meaning variable names ?A,?B,?C are arbitrary), but again this is all well documented.